# Cannot read property 'image_url' of undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react and I am trying to show data
 but I am getting the error

No Data is appear when i add some code about image_url, title,source_url etc....

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'image_url' of undefined

In [Recipe.js](https://github.com/zinmyoswe/React-Recipe-Search-Project/blob/master/src/components/Recipe.js),

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Recipe extends Component {
    render() {
        const {
            image_url,
            title,
            source_url,
            publisher,
            recipe_id
        } = this.props.recipe;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Recipe</h1>
                <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div className="card">
                        <img src={image_url} className="img-card-top" style={{height:"14rem"}} alt="recipe" />
                        <div className="card-body text-capitalize">
                            <h5>{title}</h5>
                            <h6 className="text-warning text-slanted">
                                provided by {publisher}
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-primary">Details</button>
                            <a href="{source_url}" className="btn btn-outline-dark mx-2">Recipe url</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

In **ReactList.js**,

```js
<div className="row">
             {recipes.map (recipe => {
                return <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id} recipe={recipe}
                  />;
             })}
           </div>
       </div>
   <Recipe />
</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Try console.log(this.props.recipe) before the return statement to see what the recipe object contains.  It's likely that source_url is undefined.

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the props for the Recipe component?

Comment: Thank, bro Jon Warren !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error occur as you use two time `<Recipe />` in **RecipeList.js**,

Removed one `<Recipe />`, 
error will **solve**

Change

```js
        <div className="row">
             {recipes.map (recipe => {
                return <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id} recipe={recipe}
                  />;
             })}
           </div>
       </div>
   <Recipe />
</React.Fragment>
```

To

```js
        <div className="row">
             {recipes.map (recipe => {
                return <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id} recipe={recipe}
                  />;
             })}
           </div>
       </div>
</React.Fragment>
```